# Fill DIV containers

Tags: php, html

Please see my code below. The goal is the following. When a user presses the button, the function `main.php` should be executed. Once it's finished, the content of DIV `opt_container` should be filled by running function `ganttchart.php`. Indeed I don't know how to:

1. execute `ganttchart.php` right after `main.php`.
2. run `main.php` from `form`.

Since I'm newbie in PHP, any suggestions will be very helpful to me.

```
<div id="fragment-2">
    <table width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td width="100%"> 
                <form name="optform" method="post" action="">
                    <div class="buttons">
                        <a href="" class="regular" onclick="click_function();return false;">
                        <img src="images/opt.png" alt=""/> Run optimizaton 
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </td>
        </tr>
     </table>
</div>

<div id="opt_container">

</div>

<script language="javascript">
function click_function() {
     $('#opt_container').load('optim/mainOptim.php');
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do cannot be done only in PHP. PHP script is executed at remote server, which means that a request need to be called in order php to return something. User operates on his local (client) machine.

onclick is a handler to execute javascript code, not php. You need to create javascript function, perform ajax request to php code you want to execute and then, the response place in html document. But the response should already be done by what ganttchart.php do.

Comment: Could you please post some web-link with examples?

Comment: http://www.howtoplaza.com/how-to-make-ajax-calls-with-jquery

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/5-ways-to-make-ajax-calls-with-jquery/

And check other results from google: https://www.google.pl/search?sourceid=chrome&client=ubuntu&channel=cs&ie=UTF-8&q=how+to+make+ajax+call+with+jquery

Comment: Please look at the updated thread. I'm expecting the content of 'main.php' to be shown in DIV opt_container, although it does not work this way. What could be wrong?

Comment: Have you added jquery to your <head>?
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" ></script>

Comment: You need to add return false; to your onclick handler

<a href="" class="regular" onclick="click_function();return false;">

Anchor element's default behaviour is to  redirect to the address in href attribute. In this case this is the same page, so the script is being executed but you won't see result as the page reloads due to clicking on link

Answer (score 1):

You are not posting any data to the server side from your `<form>`. It would be simpler to just make these GWT parameters i your `<img src=""/>`. No need to post the form now.

For example:

```
<div class="scrollbar" id="chart">
    <img src="ganttchart.php?param1=foo&param2=bar">
</div>
```

Otherwise, you need the following flow. Plenty of examples of each step can be found on Google.

1. Load the host webpage.
2. Have the user XHR the needed parameters to run.php and do your calcs to your server (using some JS in the host page).
3. Set the '' to the needed ganttchart.php request for the desired image. You'll likely want an 'id' to identify the transaction from (2). i.e. ganttchart.php?id=123 (done using some JS in the host page)

Comment: Do I understand correctly you assume that 'param1=foo&param2=bar' might be outputs of my function 'main.php'? If it's correct, then this is not what I need. 'main.php' stores some data in DB, and 'ganttchart.php' create a chart using DB data.

Comment: The params should be the inputs to the function. Why not combine run.php and ganttchart.php? No need for extra calls or passing data back and forth with the database and form posts. If you must do it using the database, then send the data with an AJAX request, not a form POST.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if you want php to run someting you can either access its file, include it in your file, or request it via XHR.

In your case, you want your main.php file to execute when a user presses the button. With that said, you can use the ff. code as a basis:

```
<!-- 
 note: This code is just an example, 
       your code may vary to according 
       to your requirements.
 -->

 <form action="" method="get">

     <input type="hidden" name="run_main_function" value="yes"/>

     <input type="submit" />

 </form>

 <?php

 if( isset( $_GET['run_main_function'] ) ):

    require_once 'path/to/your/main.php';

    /* execute something from your main.php */

    require_once 'path/to/your/ganttchart.php';

    /* execute some functions in your ganttchart.php */

    $result = function_from_ganttchart();

?>

 <div id="opt_container">

        <table width="100%">

            <tr>

                <td width="100%"> 

                    <div class="scrollbar" id="chart">

                        <img src="<?php echo $result; ?>">

                    </div>

                </td>

            </tr>

 </div
</php   
    endif;  
?>
```

Or you can you javascript to request to content of your gantt chart via XHR.

Thanks :)

Comment: I tried out your example. See updated thread. Don't know why, but when I click the button, it redirects me to index.php page...

Comment: My question is, how does your ganttchart.php produces an image file? Through $_GET request variables or $_POST, etc? I am not sure. Thanks

Comment: [Don't know why, but when I click the button, it redirects me to index.php page] - Strange, unless you are loading different modules via index.php as a controller.

Comment: I'm using JPGRAPH library: http://jpgraph.net/download/manuals/chunkhtml/ch05s05.html So, if I understand correctly both GET and POST are fine.

Comment: Yes,exactly,I'm loading DIV content via index.php as a controller.

Comment: What does you main.php does? is it a module? what specific functions are you using there?

Comment: Clicking submit button submits the form, which means you leave the current page on go to the new one, specified in action attribute of the form.

Comment: your image href is fine as long as it meet your requirements. see this link: [link](http://jpgraph.net/features/src/new_line1.php)

Comment: [Clicking submit button submits the form, which means you leave the current page on go to the new one, specified in action attribute of the form] - that's correct, that's why we put action = "", if it's not working in your end, then try copying the url of your page and put it as action :)

Comment: The code is working now. Finally I implemented it in the way suggested by Zefiryn as it's simply more clear for me. Thanks.